# Touch in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, touch

This is the return data I get from a touch event. Conspicuously missing are any useful touch X/Y coords (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/changedTouches). This is a hopelessly generic question, but nonetheless, any ideas? The "event" object passed to the function executed on touch:

```
{
      "originalEvent": {
        "isTrusted": true
      },
      "type": "touchstart",
      "timeStamp": 1450388006795,
      "jQuery203026962137850932777": true,
      "which": 0,
      "view": "$WINDOW",
      "target": {},
      "shiftKey": false,
      "metaKey": false,
      "eventPhase": 3,
      "currentTarget": {},
      "ctrlKey": false,
      "cancelable": true,
      "bubbles": true,
      "altKey": false,
      "delegateTarget": {},
      "handleObj": {
        "type": "touchstart",
        "origType": "touchstart",
        "data": null,
        "guid": 2026,
        "namespace": ""
      },
      "data": null
    }
```

Now, this IS in an angular UI modal in canvas, but mouse events work fine. Here is my element btw:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, model){
                //scope.canvasElem = element[0].children[0].children[0];
                scope.canvasElem = angular.element($('.touchScreen'))[0];
                scope.ctx = scope.canvasElem.getContext('2d');
```

Here is an example of how I bind:

```
element.bind('touchstart', scope.touchStart);
```

Edit, and here is a mousedown event object for comparison:

```
{
  "originalEvent": {
    "isTrusted": true
  },
  "type": "mousedown",
  "timeStamp": 1450389131400,
  "jQuery20309114612976554781": true,
  "toElement": {},
  "screenY": 436,
  "screenX": 726,
  "pageY": 375,
  "pageX": 726,
  "offsetY": 81,
  "offsetX": 41,
  "clientY": 375,
  "clientX": 726,
  "buttons": 1,
  "button": 0,
  "which": 1,
  "view": "$WINDOW",
  "target": {},
  "shiftKey": false,
  "relatedTarget": null,
  "metaKey": false,
  "eventPhase": 3,
  "currentTarget": {},
  "ctrlKey": false,
  "cancelable": true,
  "bubbles": true,
  "altKey": false,
  "delegateTarget": {},
  "handleObj": {
    "type": "mousedown",
    "origType": "mousedown",
    "data": null,
    "guid": 2025,
    "namespace": ""
  },
  "data": null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using jQuery, or at least a jQuery-like implementation. jQuery does not copy all the touch event properties to the normalized event wrapper. You can however find them under the `originalEvent` object though.

The `originalEvent` property contains the native touch event, which you can use according to the specification.

For example, code like this:

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(e) {
    // Access the original event like this:
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
});
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the reply, can you elaborate on how I get to that wrapper please?

Comment: @VSO I added a sample of how to log the original event object to the console.

Comment: I tried that, all it returns is: { "isTrusted": true}. The properties in the original object (in my question post) is all that I have access to. I really hope I am missing something.

Comment: @VSO Are you using jQuery, or something jQuery like? Perhaps the property you need is not enumerated by the console, but is still there if you access it by name.

Comment: Alexander, it might be jQuery lite or whatever comes pre-packaged with angular. I will look into it. Again, I appreciate the help, it narrows things down.

Comment: @VSO I was wondering if that might be the case. Adding the full jQuery might help.